# Only one group capture several times

Tags: regex

**String:**

```
50-60*70/50+(1+7-(9+51))+5*9/10
```

**Want:**

```
9 +51
```

**Tried:**

```
(?:\(|\G[\+\*\/-])\K(\d+)
```

**Result:**

```
1 7 9 51
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a PCRE regex to get the numbers that can be preceded with math operators inside `(...)` that has no inner `()`.

Use

```
(?:\(|(?!^)\G)\K[+*\/-]?\d+(?=[^()]*\))
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS1mF6/1)

Explanation:

- `(?:\(|(?!^)\G)\K` - Find `(` or the end of the previous successful match, and omit the match text currently stored in the memory (with `\K`)
- `[+*\/-]?` - one or zero operators
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - but only if followed by zero or more characters other than `(` and `)` up to the closing `)`.

Note that in your regex, you omit the math operators since they are before `\K` and you find the numbers after the math operators or `(` (and after the end of each successful match, that is why you get `1`, `7`, `9`, `51`.